# Repeat transformation for all variables in R

Tags: r

I have 84 variables and I need to create new 42 variables. Each variable has a value from 1 to 3. Every new variable will have a value from 1 to 7. The value of the first new variable depends on the value first and second variable (code below). I write code with this rule and everything works.

But I don't know how to repeat this code for other variables. The second new variable must be based on the third and fourth variable, the third new variable on the fifth and sixth etc (*new_var2 = ITEM3 & ITEM4, new_var3 = ITEM5 & ITEM6....*).

Thanks for any help

```
mydata<-within(mydata, {
  new_var1[ITEM1==3 & ITEM2==3]<-"7"
  new_var1[ITEM1==3 & ITEM2==2]<-"6"
  new_var1[ITEM1==3 & ITEM2==1]<-"5"
  new_var1[ITEM1==2 & ITEM2==1]<-"4"
  new_var1[ITEM1==2 & ITEM2==2]<-"4"
  new_var1[ITEM1==2 & ITEM2==3]<-"4"
  new_var1[ITEM1==1 & ITEM2==1]<-"3"
  new_var1[ITEM1==1 & ITEM2==2]<-"2"
  new_var1[ITEM1==1 & ITEM2==3]<-"1"
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
recode_function <- function(x, y){
    case_when(
        x == 3 & y == 3 ~ 7, 
        x == 3 & y == 2 ~ 6,
        x == 3 & y == 1 ~ 5, 
        x == 2  ~ 4, 
        x == 1 & y == 1 ~ 3, 
        x == 1 & y == 2 ~ 2, 
        x == 1 & y == 3 ~ 1, 
        TRUE ~ NA_real_
    )
}

dat <- tibble(
    ITEM1 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
    ITEM2 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
    ITEM3 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
    ITEM4 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
    ITEM5 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
    ITEM6 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
    ITEM7 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
    ITEM8 = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE)
)

firsts <- dat %>% select(seq(1,8, by=2))
seconds <- dat %>% select(seq(2,8, by=2))
out <- sapply(1:4, function(i)recode_function(firsts[,i], seconds[,i]))
head(firsts)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#      ITEM1 ITEM3 ITEM5 ITEM7
#      <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     3     1     3     1
# 2     1     3     3     3
# 3     2     3     1     1
# 4     1     1     2     2
# 5     1     2     1     2
# 6     2     1     2     3
head(seconds)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#      ITEM2 ITEM4 ITEM6 ITEM8
#      <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     3     2     2
# 2     1     1     2     3
# 3     3     1     1     1
# 4     1     1     3     3
# 5     3     3     1     2
# 6     2     1     3     3
head(out)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    5    1    6    2
# [2,]    3    5    6    7
# [3,]    4    5    3    3
# [4,]    3    3    4    4
# [5,]    1    4    3    4
# [6,]    4    3    4    7
```